# Calculating with Function in Bash

Tags: bash, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have a project assignment during my study on Linux and decided to make a program to predict data with Linear Regression. The program is using Bash and is still far away from finishing. Here is an example of the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables for data
src="data.csv"

# Read data
IFS='.' readarray -t array < "$src"

# Remove header
unset "array[0]"

# Display content
for item in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$item"
done

# Initialize variables x and y
x=()
y=()

# Data separation loop
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
    row=("${array[$i]}")
    x+=("${row[0]}")
    y+=("${row[1]}")
done

# Calculate mean and standard deviation for x and y
calculate_mean() {
    local data=("${@}")
    local sum=0
    local mean

    for item in "${data[@]}"; do
        sum=$(awk "BEGIN{ sum+=$sum+$item }END{ print sum }")
    done

    mean=$(awk "BEGIN{ print $sum / ${#data[@]} }")
    echo "$mean"
}

calculate_std_deviation() {
    local data=("${@}")
    local mean=$1
    local sum_squares=0
    local variance
    local std_deviation

    for item in "${data[@]}"; do
        sum_squares=$(awk "BEGIN{ sum+=$sum_squares+(diff*diff )} END{ print sum }")
    done

    variance=$(awk  "BEGIN{ print $sum_squares / ${#data[@]} }")
    std_deviation=$(awk "BEGIN{ print sqrt($variance) }")
    echo "$std_deviation"
}

x_mean=$(calculate_mean "${x[@]}")
x_std=$(calculate_std_deviation "${x[@]}" "$x_mean")
y_mean=$(calculate_mean "${y[@]}")
y_std=$(calculate_std_deviation "${y[@]}" "$y_mean")

echo "Mean x: $x_mean"
echo "Standard deviation x: $x_std"
echo "Mean y: $y_mean"
echo "Standard deviation y: $y_std"
```

When I ran it on the Kali Terminal, the program stopped after printing the array. I was confused while trying to solve and figure it out. I know the program didn't show the part of linear regression, but the problem here can't make me continue, also I'm still searching for an effective and easy way to implement it on Bash

Im not sure what is it. I just expect it to show The mean and standard deviation from the declared function.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I've tried to implement all the recommendations, but unfortunately, it has had no effect bc the program is still stuck

Comment: consider adding extra `echo` commands throughout the code so you can figure out where the script is stopping; the extra `echo` commands can also be used to confirm/refute that variables contain what you think they contain

Comment: awk "BEGIN{ sum+=$sum+$item }END{ print sum }"` ... the `END{...}` block requires the script to process at least one line of input, but there is no input; try running your `awk` script at the command line to see what happens

Comment: Indenting your code would be helpful to better understand the structure.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `"${row[1]}")` to contain? After `row=("${array[$i]}")`, `row` is an array with 1 element, `row[0]`, whereas `row[1]` is (by default) empty.